# fb.db.ref() is not a function - Firebase realtime with Vuejs

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

Building a basic app with auth and user profiles with Firebase realtime and Vue.js with Vuex.
I am getting this pesky error "fb.db.ref(...).then is not a function" when attempting to retrieve user details by ID through the Vuex store.

**firebaseConfig.js**

```js
import firebase from 'firebase'

// firebase init goes here
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "******",
    authDomain: "******",
    databaseURL: "******",
    projectId: "******",
    storageBucket: "******",
    messagingSenderId: "******",
    appId: "******"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// firebase utils
const db = firebase.database()
const auth = firebase.auth()
console.log('inside config - auth:', auth)
console.log('inside config db:', db)
const currentUser = auth.currentUser

export {
    db,
    auth,
    currentUser,
}
```

**Function for signup (auth and write user to db is working perfectly )**

```js
 signup() {
                this.performingRequest = true
                // first we authorize(separate to user object)
                fb.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.signupForm.email, this.signupForm.password).then(credential => {
                    // we send the user to vuex to set
                    this.$store.commit('setCurrentUser', credential.user)
                    // create user obj in firebase collection
                    
                    fb.db.ref(`users/${credential.user.uid}`).set({
                        name: this.signupForm.name,
                        email: this.signupForm.email
    
                    }).then(() => {
                        this.$store.dispatch('fetchUserProfile')
                        this.performingRequest = false
                        this.$router.push('/dashboard')
                    }).catch(err => {
                        console.log('signup() - creating fb user object', err)
                        this.performingRequest = false
                        this.errorMsg = err.message
                    })
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log('signup() - creating fb auth object', err)
                    this.performingRequest = false
                    this.errorMsg = err.message
                })
            },
```

**Store (where I am getting the error)**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
const fb = require('../firebaseConfig.js')

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    currentUser: null,
    userProfile: {}
  },
  mutations: {
      setCurrentUser(state, val) {
      state.currentUser = val
    },
      setUserProfile(state, val) {
      state.userProfile = val
    }
  },

  actions: {
    fetchUserProfile({ commit, state }) {
      fb.db.ref(`users/${state.currentUser.uid}`).then(res => { //ERROR FROM THIS LINE
          commit('setUserProfile', res.data())
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
    }
  },

  modules: {
  }
})
```

**Index.html with snippet (although no sure if i even need this)**

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>

    <script src="/__/firebase/7.13.2/firebase.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Any hints much appreciated!! 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read data, then you need to use `once()`:

```
  actions: {
    fetchUserProfile({ commit, state }) {
      fb.db.ref(`users/${state.currentUser.uid}`).once('value').then(res => { 
          commit('setUserProfile', res.val())
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
    }
  },
```

check here for more info:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once

Comment: Thanks @PeterHaddad this worked perfectly. Have been using Firestore so this threw me off-track.